# Mapping array objects and updating state variable. data is lost

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state

I want an array of days to update to same start time and end time and update it a state variable. When i am mapping the array of days to the update state variable form. When checking the console logs. either only starttime updates or endtime or only 1 day is updated to the state variable

```
const daystime={
    sunday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    monday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    tuesday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    wednesday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    thursday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    friday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
    saturday: {
      start: "3000",
      end: "3000",
    },
  }
  const [form, setForm] = React.useState(daystime);
  const [singleStartTime, setSingleStartTime] = React.useState(new Date());
  const [singleEndTime, setSingleEndTime] = React.useState(new Date());
useEffect(() => {
    if(value==='Same Timing'){
    let starttime='3000'
    let endtime='3000'
    if (singleStartTime._d) {
      if(singleStartTime._d.getMinutes().toString().length<2)
      starttime = singleStartTime._d.getHours().toString() +'0'+singleStartTime._d.getMinutes().toString();
      else
      starttime =singleStartTime._d.getHours().toString() +singleStartTime._d.getMinutes().toString();
      
      days.map((day) => {
        pass(day.title, "start", starttime);
        return "";
      });
    }
    if (singleEndTime._d) {
      if(singleEndTime._d.getMinutes().toString().length<2)
      endtime = singleEndTime._d.getHours().toString() +'0'+singleEndTime._d.getMinutes().toString();
      else
      endtime =singleEndTime._d.getHours().toString() +singleEndTime._d.getMinutes().toString();
      days.map((day) => {
        pass(day.title, "end", endtime);
        return "";
      });
    }}
  }, [singleStartTime, singleEndTime, days]);

  const pass = (day, side, time) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [`${day}`]: { ...form[`${day}`], [`${side}`]: time },
    });
  };
```

Comment: did it fix your problem? just updated the answer and added the codesanbox.

Comment: I found a solution myself. I used the previous value provided by useState to update the new state and hence it would wait before changing the new state. But yes your Answer did also work fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

- Problem

Setting State works asyncronously.

So if you do : `setCounter(counter + 1); setCounter(counter + 1);`  it **doesn't** add 2 to counter (instead it adds only 1 to it), because you should let the state variable to update, before applying the new State to it. ([see it live](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHH8XAI2K3EX))

In your case, you are changing startDate and endDate in your state variable for 7 days (28 state updates), without letting the `form` state variable to update :

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({'sunday': {start: 1, end: 2},
                                    'monday': {start: 1, end: 2}})
setForm([...form, {sunday: {...form.sunday, start: 100}}]);
setForm([...form, {sunday: {...form.sunday, end: 200}}]);
// After update, the form will be: {'sunday': {start: 1, end: 200}, ...}
// !!! PROBELM !!! You shouldn't use multiple setForms right after each others !!!
```

- Solution:

Instead of setting the state multiple times without letting the new state to apply, you should first calculate your new state, and then apply it.

(Like `let v = 1 + 1; setCounter(counter => counter + v);`)

(Solution2: You can also use callbacks like `setCounter(counter => counter + 1); setCounter(counter => counter + 1);`, so it'll use the prev state.)

[Run It On Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shockley-2ur2b?file=/src/App.js)

```
useEffect(() => {
 // clone state here
  let newForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form))
  ...
    if (singleStartTime._d) {
    ...      
      days.forEach(day => {
        newForm = {
          ...newForm,
          [day.title]: { ...newForm[day.title], start: starttime }
        };
      });
    }
   // Do the same for EndTime
   // Apply the new state
   setForm(newForm)
...
}
```

[Run It On Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shockley-2ur2b?file=/src/App.js)